# Check for duplication of number in ArrayList - Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm currently making a sudoku program, however my current code seems to fail me. The script below should put out a print "Inconsistent sudoku puzzle" if a row contains the same number several times, but sadly it doesn't.. I've tried several different attempts but no succes.

```
public void checkRow() {
    int count = 0;

    for(int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
        for(int a = 1; a < 10; a++) {
            for (int i=0; i < list.get(j).length(); i++) {
                if(list.get(j).charAt(i) == a) {
                    count++;
                    if(count >= 2) {
                        System.out.println("Inconsistent sudoku puzzle");
                        count = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            count = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the collection of all my error checks:

```
public void errorCheck() {
    this.checkRow();
    this.checkColumn();
    this.checkBox();
}
```

Here i load it into my main. The code is a lot more elaborate, but these should be the sections involving the issue.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {
    Sudoku s = new Sudoku("C:\\Users\\caspe\\Downloads\\Sudoku001.sdk");
    s.printBoard();
    s.errorCheck();
    s.getNum();


    while(getNum() > 0) {
        System.out.println("Next move, please (row , column , value )");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int row = scanner.nextInt();
        int column = scanner.nextInt() ;
        int value = scanner.nextInt();
        if (s.moves(row, column, value)); {
            s.errorCheck();
        }

        s.printBoard();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
if(list.get(j).charAt(i) == a)
```

is always `false` because you compare a `char` with an `int`.
Replace it with

```
if((list.get(j).charAt(i)-'0') == a)
```

`list.get(j).charAt(i)-'0'` gives you the numeric representation of the char

Answer (score 2):

#### The issue

You're using `charAt` and trying to compare the result of that to a number:

```
list.get(j).charAt(i) == a
```

However doing so you're comparing the [ascii](http://www.asciitable.com/) value of the character to the number.

*Example*:

```
String a = "3";
System.out.println((int) a.charAt(0)); // This prints 51
```

---

#### The solution

If you wanted to compare number values you'd have to do something like this:

```
String a = "3";
System.out.println(Character.getNumericValue(a.charAt(0))); // This prints 3
```

`Character.getNumericValue(a.charAt(0))` returns the number value of the character.

---

#### Implementation

Implementing that into your code would look like this:

```
Character.getNumericValue(list.get(j).charAt(i)) == a
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is: 
'if(list.get(j).charAt(i) == a)'

its comparing with the "a" value on the ascii table